# Aggregate strings on the basis of a column in R, keep only first/last

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr

I have a dummy dataset like so:

```
  x  y
1 1  test1
2 2  test2
3 2  test3
4 3  test4
5 3  test5
```

I want to aggregate it on the basis of the values in `x`, but instead of concatenating or running a maximum frequency checks, I simply want to display the last/first value for that value of `x` (based on the row numbers). I want to know how to display both, the last and the first value. Simply removing duplicates based on `x` will not give me flexibility to choose which value of `y` i can choose.

My output would be like this (last):

```
  x  y
1 1  test1
2 2  test3
3 3  test5
```

Or like this (first):

```
  x  y
1 1  test1
2 2  test2
3 3  test4
```

I have a large dataset of 1M+ rows. Help will be appreciated. I've tried aggregate and ddply approaches.

Comment: How did your search for "select first or last value in r" work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dplyr::distinct()`, which keeps the unique row based on the variable, and if you specify `.keep_all` parameter to be `TRUE`, you get the first row for each distinct value of the specified variable:

To get the first:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
      distinct(x, .keep_all = TRUE)

#  x     y
#1 1 test1
#2 2 test2
#3 3 test4
```

To get the last row, you can reverse your data frame by sorting it with `row_number()` in descending order and then use `distinct()`:

```
df %>% 
      arrange(desc(row_number())) %>% 
      distinct(x, .keep_all = TRUE)

#  x     y
#1 3 test5
#2 2 test3
#3 1 test1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `duplicated`

```
df[!duplicated(df$x, fromLast=TRUE),]
  x     y
1 1 test1
3 2 test3
5 3 test5

df[!duplicated(df$x),]
  x     y
1 1 test1
2 2 test2
4 3 test4
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use `data.table` since you said your data is very large. I have given two example, for each first/last value, both of which give the same result. The method using `setkey` will be faster.

```
library(data.table)
```

**First value**

*Method 1:*

```
dt[dt[,list(keep=.I[which.min(.I)]),by=.(x)][,keep]]
```

*Method 2:*

```
setkey(dt,x)
dt[J(unique(x)),mult="first"]


   x     y
1: 1 test1
2: 2 test2
3: 3 test4
```

**Last value**

*Method 1:*

```
dt[dt[,list(keep=.I[which.max(.I)]),by=.(x)][,keep]]
```

*Method 2:*

```
setkey(dt,x)
dt[J(unique(x)),mult="last"]



   x     y
1: 1 test1
2: 2 test3
3: 3 test5
```

**Data**

```
dt <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), y = structure(1:5, .Label = c("test1", 
"test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("x", 
"y"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000140788>)
```

***Edit***: Added in the `setkey()` method.